# WaterMark with PHP

Tags: php, gd, watermark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add an image onto an image in PHP like a watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217820/how-can-i-add-an-image-onto-an-image-in-php-like-a-watermark)

I'm working with PHP and I want to add a watermark in some photos.

Something like this: [image: WaterMark]

[NOTE THE 9GAG.COM/GAG/4203228; like a footer]

I know that the watermark can be added with the GD library, but I don't know how to add it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess [imagecopymerge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) is the GD function you are looking for.